# Monotouch - sqlite and hebrew characters

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.ios

I am trying the following query using a preloaded sqlite DB in a Monotouch project:

```sql
select * from my_table where id not in (1,2,3,4) and field not in ('תווים בעברית') order by RANDOM() limit 55;
```

but I keep getting a SQLiteException. If I replace the hebrew string with english characters it works fine.

How can I solve this issue?

Also notice that the same exact query works fine in an Android project (written in Java).

EDIT (Code)

```cs
var conn = new SQLiteConnection (System.IO.Path.Combine (folder, "mydb.db3"));

string sql = select * from my_table where id not in (1,2,3,4) and field not in ('תווים בעברית') order by RANDOM() limit 55;

IEnumerable<myObject> objects = conn.Query<myObject> (sql.ToString()); //Here is the exception
```

The Exception thrown:

> SQLite.SQLiteException: near "lim": syntax error
>     at SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare2 (IntPtr db, System.String query) [0x00000] in :0
>     at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.Prepare () [0x00000] in :0
>     at SQLite.SQLiteCommand+d_*0`1[MyAppName.Question].MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
>     at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyAppName.Question].AddEnumerable (IEnumerable`1 enumerable) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
>     at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyAppName.Question]..ctor (IEnumerable`1 collection) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
>     at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[Question] (IEnumerable`1 source) [0x00000] in :0
>     at SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteQuery[Question] () [0x00000] in :0
>     at SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Query[Question] (System.String query, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in :0
>     at MyAppName.DBHelper.getQuestions (Int32 level) [0x000f1] in /Users/mmac/Documents/projects/MyAppNameMono/MyAppName/MyAppName/dal/DBHelper.cs:43
>     at MyAppName.AppDelegate.m*_0 (System.Object ) [0x00002] in /Users/mmac/Documents/projects/MyAppNameMono/MyAppName/MyAppName/AppDelegate.cs:36

Comment: There are several data library to use SQLite, which one are you using ? also please show the code (there's many way to do this and it could affect only some of them)

Comment: I am using a dll file I have downloaded from Xamarin's component store: http://components.xamarin.com/view/sqlite-net

Comment: Thank you very much for keeping the error message a secret.

Comment: Sorry. I added the exception to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
near "lim": syntax error
```

This error message indicates that the last six characters of your query string got chopped off, i.e., that MonoTouch does not compute the string length correctly.

Report this bug to Xamarin, and/or try to upgrade.

To work around this, try to pass the string value as a parameter (which is a good idea in the first place to avoid formatting problems and [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/)):

```cs
string sql = "select ... field not in (?) ...";
string value = "תווים בעברית";
IEnumerable<myObject> objects = conn.Query<myObject>(sql, value);
```

Comment: Excellent, this solution works, Thank you!
There is one issue though, if value consists more the one condition (e.g. "cond1,cond2") it doesn't work, there is no exception though, just an empty result set. Do you have an idea what can cause it?

Comment: Each parameter is a single value. You would have to use `IN (?,?)` and `Query(sql, val1, val2)`.